# Print a list of dishes selected and added using a different button on angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

[Photo of what we have to build on angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2ytC.png)

[What we have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvGV8.png)

[What we have so far II](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQvUq.png)

We need to build a simple ordering system and we cannot figure out how to print several of the plates selected. We have only managed to print one plate when selecting it and pressing the + button.
Does anyone know how to make the selections stay, even when selecting new dishes? Thank you in advance for the help!

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PLATOS } from './lista-platos';
import { Plato } from './plato';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Restaurante';

  selectedOption!: Plato;
  printedOption!: Plato;

  options = PLATOS;

  print() {
    
    this.printedOption = this.selectedOption;
    console.log('My input: ', this.selectedOption);
  }
}
```

```css
import { Plato } from './plato';

export const PLATOS: Plato[] = [
  { name: 'Macarrones con chorizo', price: 8.90 },
  { name: 'Pasta al pesto', price: 10.20 },
  { name: 'Pizza', price: 7.80 },
  { name: 'Rollitos primavera', price: 5.50 },
  { name: 'Arroz tres delicias', price: 6.70 }
];
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <option *ngFor="let o of options">{{ o.name }} ({{ o.price }}€)</option>
</select>
<button (click)="print()">+</button>

<!-- <div *ngFor="let o of options">
  <div *ngIf="o == printedOption">
    <p>{{ printedOption }}</p>
  </div>
</div> -->
<p>{{ printedOption }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gxbejh

app-component ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PLATOS } from './lista-platos';
import { Plato } from './plato';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedOption: any;
  options = PLATOS;
  takenPlatos: Plato[] = [];
  totalPrice: number = 0;

  addPlato(plato: Plato) {
    this.takenPlatos.push(plato);
    this.totalPrice += plato.price;
  }

  removePlato(index: number) {
    this.totalPrice -= this.takenPlatos[index].price;
    this.takenPlatos.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

app-component html:

```
<h2>ORDEN</h2>

Consumicion:
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <option *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index" [ngValue]="option">
    {{ option.name }} ({{ option.price }}€)
  </option>
</select>
<button (click)="addPlato(selectedOption)">+</button>

<ng-container *ngIf="takenPlatos.length > 0">
  <h3>Consumiciones:</h3>
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let plato of takenPlatos; let i = index">
      <th>{{ plato.name }}</th>
      <th>{{ plato.price }} €</th>
      <th><button (click)="removePlato(i)">-</button></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
      <th>{{ totalPrice }} €</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help!!! Do you know any good angular courses/tutorials by any chance? Our teacher is not great.

Comment: I find it best to read some books on Angular and JS - there are many available, so go with something published after 2016 at least. Another thing I'd strongly suggest is building your own simple projects parallel to doing projects from the books. The books will teach you a lot, but trying to conceptualize and realize your own ideas - while looking for the best solutions for the problems arising from the limited knowledge - you'd progress much faster and will have fun aswell :) Please consider voting my answer aswell, if you thing it's a good and useful one. Thank you!

Comment: Also, you can change removePlato method to have just `this.totalPrice -= this.takenPlatos[index].price; this.takenPlatos.splice(index, 1);`. I've edited the answer (I didn't change the stackblitz).